# Dependency injection of IHttpContextAccessor vs passing parameter up the method chain

Tags: java, .net, asp.net-core

Our application calls many external API's which take a session token of the current user as input. So what we currently do is in a controller, get the session token for the user and pass it into a service which in turn might call another service or some API client. To give an idea, we end up with something like this (example is .NET but something similar is I think possible in Java)

```
public IActionResult DoSomething(string something)
{
  this.someService.DoSomethingForUser(this.HttpContext.SessionToken, something);
  return View();
}
```

And then we have

```
public class SomeService
{
  private readonly IApiClient apiClient;

  public SomeService(IApiClient apiClient)
  {
    this.apiClient = apiClient;
  }

  public void DoSomethingForUser(string sessionToken, something)
  {
    this.apiClient.DoSomethingForUser(sessionToken, something);
  }
}
```

It can also happen that in `SomeService` another service is injected which in turn calls the `IApiClient` instead of `SomeService` calling `IApiClient` directly, basically adding another "layer".

We had a discussion with the team if it isn't better to instead of passing the session token, inject it using DI so you get something like this:

```
public IActionResult DoSomething(string something)
{
  this.someService.DoSomethingForUser(something);
  return View();
}
```

And then we have

```
public class SomeService
{
  private readonly IUserService userService;
  private readonly IApiClient apiClient;

  public SomeService(IUserService userService, IApiClient apiClient)
  {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.apiClient = apiClient;
  }

  public void DoSomethingForUser(string something)
  {
    this.apiClient.DoSomethingForUser(userService.SessionToken, something);
  }
}
```

The `IUserService` would have an `IHttpContextAccessor` injected:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

  public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  public string SessionToken => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SessionToken;
}
```

The benefits of this pattern are I think pretty clear. Especially with many services, it keeps the code "cleaner" and you end up with less boilerplate code to pass a token around.

Still, I don't like it. To me the downsides of this pattern are more important than its benefit:

- I like that passing the token in the methods is concise. It is clear that the service needs some sort of authentication token for it to function. I'm not sure if you can call it a side effect but the fact that a session token is magically injected three layers deep is impossible to tell just by reading the code
- Unit testing is a bit more tedious if you have to Mock the IUserService
- You run into problems when calling this in another thread, e.g. calling `SomeService` from another thread. Although these problems can be mitigated by injecting another concrete type of IUserService which gets the token from some place else, it feels like a chore.

To me it strongly feels like an anti pattern but apart from the arguments above it is mostly a feeling. There was a lot of discussion and not everybody was convinced that it was a bad idea. Therefor, my question is, is it an anti pattern or is it perfectly valid? What are some strong arguments for and against it, hopefully so there can be not much debate that this pattern is indeed, either perfectly valid or something to avoid.

Comment: This is opinion based. Perhaps reword to avoid extended discussion. Your solution is *not* what I would consider an antipattern. In fact, this is probably how I would do it. The only potential downside is the ASP.NET dependency hitting other layers of your stack (i.e. the context accessor being pushed down into an infrastructure layer... but that seems minor to me). The mocking is a normal thing; I wouldn't even worry about it. I know how to avoid the threading issue, but I'm loath to answer an opinion oriented question.

Comment: I understand, on the other hand, sometimes opinions are just wrong. "I like methods that are 300 lines long" can be an opinion, but there are clear, undeniable arguments why it is a bad idea.

Comment: I'll just continue in the comments. If your user service is request/transient scoped, and you start a thread or queue to a background worker to do threaded stuff, once you get your token, it can be used for those threads. The user service obvious *can't* be a singleton or some other longer lifetime.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that indeed the service cannot be a singleton but that is indeed a downside. If it is transient scoped, passing it in a Task.Run() call (not saying that is a good idea) doesn't work right, since in a worker thread the IHttpContextAccessor is not available or at least, HttpContext would return null.

Comment: In that case you'd have to force the user service to cache the token immediately upon instantiation or call a method on the user service to cache the token before passing to a task... now you might be venturing into anti-pattern territory perhaps. I think it's up to you at this point, which is why I still consider your question opinion-based. But I'd still probably do something similar to this anyway and just move on until I'd thought of something better. One thing that would not be ideal is passing primitives in DI.

Comment: Actually, one more thing. I'd try not to chain the session token across calls *at all*. It would be better to establish some new token and correlate it back to the original imho.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the main point is to enable your desired separation of concerns. I think it is a good question if expressed in those terms. As Kit says, different people may prefer different solutions.

**REQUEST SCOPED OBJECTS**

These occur quite naturally in APIs. Consider the following example, where a UI calls an Orders API, then the Orders API forwards the JWT to an upstream Billing API. A unique Request ID is also sent, in case the flow experiences a temporary problem. If the flow is retried, the Request ID can be used by APIs to prevent data duplication. Yet business logic should not need to know about either the Request ID or the JWT.

[image]

**BUSINESS LOGIC CLASS DESIGN**

I would start by designing my logic classes with my desired inputs, then work out the DI later. In my example the OrderService class might use claims to get the user identity and also for authorization. But I would not want it to know about HTTP level concerns:

```cs
public class OrderService
{
  private readonly IBillingApiClient billingClient;

  public OrderService(IBillingApiClient billingClient, ClaimsPrincipal user)
  {
    this.billingClient = billingClient;
  }

  public async void CreateOrder(OrderInput data)
  {
    this.Authorize();
    var order = this.CreateOrder(data);
    await this.billingClient.CreateInvoice(order);
  }
}
```

**DI SETUP**

To enable my preferred business logic, I would write a little DI plumbing, so that I could inject request scoped dependencies in my preferred way. First, when the app starts, I would create a small middleware class. This will run early in the HTTP request pipeline:

```
private void ConfigureApiMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder api)
{
  api.UseMiddleware<ClientContextMiddleware>();
}
```

In the middleware class I would then create a ClientContext object from runtime data. The OrderService class will run later, after next() is called:

```
public class ClientContextMiddleware
{
  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
    var jwt = readJwt(context.Request);
    var requestId = readRequestId(context.Request);

    var holder = context.RequestServices.GetService<ClientContextHolder>();
    holder.ClientContext = new ClientContext(jwt, requestIO);

    await this.next(context);
  }
}
```

In my DI composition at application startup I would express that the API client should be created when it is first referenced. In the HTTP request pipeline, the OrderService request scoped object will be constructed after the middleware has run. The below lambda will then be invoked:

```cs
private void RegisterDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
{
  this.services.AddScoped<IApiClient>(
    ctx =>
    {
      var holder = ctx.GetService<ClientContextHolder>();
      return new ApiClient(holder.context);
    });

  this.services.AddScoped<ClientContextHolder>();
}
```

The holder object is just due to a technology limitation. The MS stack does not allow you to create new request scoped injectable objects at runtime, so you have to update an existing one. In a previous .NET tech stack, the concept of `child container per request` was made available to developers, so the holder object was not needed.

**ASYNC AWAIT**

Request scoped objects are stored against the HTTP request object, which is the correct behaviour when using async await. The current thread ID may switch, eg from 4 to 6 after the call to the Billing API.

If the OrderService class has a transient scope, it could get recreated when the flow resumes on thread 6. If this is the case, then resolution will continue to work.

**SUMMARY**

Designing inputs first, then writing some support code if needed is a good approach I think, and it is also useful to know the DI techniques. Personally I think natural request scoped objects that need to be created at runtime should be usable in DI. Some people may prefer a different approach though.

Answer (score 0):

See in dotnet the area that I am an expert is not an anti standard on the contrary it is the model that many adopt but it is not a model that I would follow for the following reasons

- it is not clear where is the token for those who read and use it being an anti clean code
- you load important information in a place that is frequently accessed by the framework in the case of .netCore
- your classes will reference a large property carrying a lot of unnecessary information when you could have created a more clean model that costs less memory and allocation time, I'm saying this because the HttpAcessor carries all the information relevant to your request

**As I would take care of readability (clean code) and improve my performance**

I would make a middleware or filter in my flow mvc where I would do the authentication part and create a class like:

```
public class TokenAuthenciationValues
{
   public string TokenClient { get; set; }
   public string TokenValue { get; set; }
}
```

Of course my method is an example but in my middleware I would implement it by loading its token values ​​after calling the necessary apis (of course this model needs an interface and it needs to be configured as .AddScoped() in the case of .net)

That way I would use it in my methods only instantiating my ITokenAuthenciationValues ​​in the constructor and I would have clear and clean information loaded in memory during the entire request

If it is necessary in the middle of the request to change the token any class can access it and change its value

I would have less memory allocated unused in my classes since the IHttpAcessor contract the ITokenAuthenciationValues ​​only has relevant information

Hope this helps